# Better Performance for setting backgroundView: willDisplayCell or init?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am just curious, what has better performance for setting a custom backgroundView of a UITableViewCell?

Option 0) Subclass of UITableViewCell init method

```
@implementation CustomCell
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier andReleases:(NSArray*)releases {

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tablecell.png"]] autorelease];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Option 1) willDisplayCell delegate method

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tablecell.png"]] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: I accept answers if they answer the question. In this case I believe you did. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option 0 is better in this case since you set the background once when you create the cell, and `willDisplayCell` will set it each time you display a cell. And since you'll reuse `UITableViewCells` you'll create cell less time then you'll display them.

But avoid premature optimization, optimize only when you feel the performance isn't good enough.